# Tkinter Text Widget - Adding Lines and Annotations Dynamically

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-text

I wish to add separator lines and annotations to a Tkinter Text widget, like what is shown in the image, which I created with photoshop to illustrate. Is there a way this can be done with Tkinter? [Text widget with lines and annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi8zr.png)

Comment: For the separators: you could try adding a blank line with a different background color.  Adjust font size to set thickness.  For the annotations: perhaps you can adapt an existing solution for adding line numbering to a Text (you just wouldn't have numbers on every line).  I'm pretty sure there's at least one question about that here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jason. With regard to adding a blank line with a different background color, what I have been doing is filling the line with spaces and applying a highlight (tag_add). How do you change the background color for a single line?

Comment: `background` is one of the options you can set for a tag - I'm assuming it's still applied even if the line is empty.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that before, but it's a good solution that will work. Thanks!